# How to sort a list of data based on three columns in the right order?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, columnsorting

Below you see a piece of code which is used to:
First sort a list of data, based on first the Entity column, second on the GREN column and third on the IC column. And then compiling the data which has the same Entity, GREN and IC column.

For some reason, I get the following error when I run the code:

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.

It is not failing when sorting the other columns and when I use less data it seems to work perfectly fine. Does anyone understand what goes wrong? And more importantly how to fix it?

```
Sub itest()

Dim EntityCol As Long, GRENCol As Long, ICCol As Long, ValueCol As Long, i As Long
Dim firstrow As Long, lastrow As Long, rngData As Range

Worksheets("FC_OUTPUT").Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

EntityCol = 4 ' column D
GRENCol = 8
ICCol = 9
ValueCol = 12 ' column L
firstrow = 7
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, EntityCol).End(xlUp).Row

With ActiveSheet.Sort
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(firstrow, EntityCol)), Order:=xlAscending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(firstrow, GRENCol)), Order:=xlAscending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(firstrow, ICCol)), Order:=xlAscending
     .SetRange Range(Cells(firstrow, 1), Cells(lastrow, 96))
     .Header = xlNo
     .Apply
End With


Set rngData = Range(Cells(firstrow, 1), Cells(lastrow, 96)) ' this line should be adjusted but you'll need to also adjust firstrow and lastrow

With rngData
' Here I'll start a loop for every row going from the end to the beginning, to prevent issues when removing rows
    For i = lastrow To firstrow Step -1
    ' Here I'll use the If statement to check if the values are the same as the previous row

        If .Cells(i, EntityCol) = .Cells(i - 1, EntityCol) And _
                .Cells(i, GRENCol) = .Cells(i - 1, GRENCol) And _
                .Cells(i, ICCol) = .Cells(i - 1, ICCol) Then
            ' This is where you'll do your addition and delete
            .Cells(i - 1, ValueCol).Value2 = .Cells(i - 1, ValueCol) + .Cells(i, ValueCol)
            .Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
Sub tgr()

    Const lEntityCol As Long = 4    'Column D
    Const lGRENCol As Long = 8      'Column H
    Const lICCol As Long = 9        'Column I
    Const lValueCol As Long = 12    'Column L
    Const lDataStartRow As Long = 7 'Actual data (not headers) starts on row 7

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim rDel As Range
    Dim hUnq As Object
    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim sDelim As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FC_OUTPUT")
    Set rData = ws.Range("A" & lDataStartRow & ":CR" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, lEntityCol).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set hUnq = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    sDelim = "|"    'This is a character that will not be in your data

    With rData
        If .Row < lDataStartRow Then Exit Sub   'No data
        .Sort Key1:=Intersect(.Cells, ws.Columns(lEntityCol)), Order1:=xlAscending, _
              Key2:=Intersect(.Cells, ws.Columns(lGRENCol)), Order2:=xlAscending, _
              Key3:=Intersect(.Cells, ws.Columns(lICCol)), Order3:=xlAscending, _
              Header:=xlNo
        aData = .Value
    End With

    For i = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)
        If Len(Trim(aData(i, lEntityCol))) > 0 _
        And Len(Trim(aData(i, lGRENCol))) > 0 _
        And Len(Trim(aData(i, lICCol))) > 0 Then
            sTemp = LCase(Trim(aData(i, lEntityCol))) & sDelim & LCase(Trim(aData(i, lGRENCol))) & sDelim & LCase(Trim(aData(i, lICCol)))
            If Not hUnq.exists(sTemp) Then
                'New unique combination of Entity, GREN, and IC found
                hUnq.Add sTemp, sTemp

                'Get the total sum of values for the unique combination
                rData.Cells(i, lValueCol).Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(ws.Columns(lValueCol), _
                                                                           ws.Columns(lEntityCol), aData(i, lEntityCol), _
                                                                           ws.Columns(lGRENCol), aData(i, lGRENCol), _
                                                                           ws.Columns(lICCol), aData(i, lICCol))
            Else
                'Not a new unique combination, add it to the list of rows to be deleted
                If rDel Is Nothing Then Set rDel = rData.Cells(i, 1) Else Set rDel = Union(rDel, rData.Cells(i, 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    If Not rDel Is Nothing Then rDel.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: The sorting part seems to work perfect (THANKS!). Yet when I check if it summed the data it only deleted the rows where it found a match.

Comment: @DutchDandy It sums as expected for me. Can you provide sample data where it's failing to sum please?

Comment: @DutchDandy The reason that isn't summing is because the defined Values column (column L, labelled `Total`) doesn't have any values in it, so there's nothing to actually sum.  Is that the correct Values column?  If it is, why doesn't it have any values?  Is it supposed to be a sum of all of the values in the subsequent dates columns?

Comment: @DutchDandy There are also a bunch of named ranges in that workbook that are resulting in `#REF!` errors.  If the named ranges are pulling information from a different workbook, that data was not included in what you shared with me.  However, there doesn't seem to be any formulas in the data, so the named ranges don't appear to be in use anyway.  Still leaves the problem of why your `Total` col doesn't actually have any values, which is why nothing's being summed.

Comment: I also tried it by defining lValueCol As Long as column 13, unfortunately without success. You are right that all the subsequent dates columns should be summed as well, but I thought I might want to tackle each problem separately.

Comment: I don't use the name ranges in this particular sheet. I think they came along with making the example data set. Is it summing with you in the subsequent columns that do have data?

Comment: @DutchDandy Yes, it sums properly as expected for me.  I have performed extensive testing at this point and can verify the code works as expected.  If you'd like to verify, then in cell J7 (your labelled `Total` column), enter this formula: `=SUM(K7:CR7)`.  In the dataset you provided me, that results in rows 7, 52, and 58 (which are E0001, AC800000, and ICNone) to have individual values of `1,920,833`; `3,644,395`; and `2,546,725` respectively which sums to a total of `8,111,953`.  When I set the `lValueCol = 10` in the code to reflect the labelled Total column J (which now has the formula...

Comment: ... in it so each row has a value), we can see that resulting row 48 (it's moved way down due to the sort) has the matching criteria of E0001, AC800000, and ICNone and the total now reflects `8,111,953` which is exactly what we manually calculated earlier.  All other resulting rows match their manual calculations also.